# Can I start training Krav Maga at 12?

Tags: krav-maga

I have started training at a Martial Arts place, about 20 minutes away from my house. They offer Taekwondo, Brazilian Jiu Jitsu, Japanese Jiu Jitsu, Judo, and **Krav Maga**. I've done MMA for about 2 years, at another place; I also did Taekwondo at another place when I was 7, and I've moved to this one not that long ago. I'm currently doing Japanese Jiu Jitsu, and I've been taking an interest in Krav Maga for a while. I've wanted to start Training in Krav Maga, but I'm only **12**. Would Krav Maga be appropriate for me?

Comment: This question has basically already been asked before, except it was for someone asking as a 14 year old. I'm going to refer you to my answer, because I think it applies very well:  https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6895/am-i-allowed-to-start-krav-maga-training-at-14/6897#6897

Comment: IMHO, no ! It's not pratical at all for normal people, you can't handle a knife after learning it. It might be useful only for some very special person. Just keep with MMA  or any other practial martial arts. That said, you can take it as a gym, for health, but not as martial art.